# LAN connection not behaving, tried every trick i know

Tags: networking, performance, ethernet

I built a new pc yesterday, installed all firmware ad driver updates (ALL of them) and ran every windows update i had to.

This is my situation:
Online Speedtest shows download speeds below 1Mbps 
Steam is downloading at 3Mbps, higher that what the speedtest shows. 
Speedtest on wifi (another device) is abt 20Mbps (that's avg for where i am).
Speedtest on other devices via LAN is on par with wifi so it is solely a problem with my system.

I have tried changing cable, port, connection between the switch and the port, run diagnostics, uninstalling and reinstalling drivers, advanced settings as jumbo frame, speed and duplex etc, reboot of the system and of the router.

When i changed speed and duplex from auto negotiation to 1Gbps, it spiked to nominal speed, just to decrease to sub 1 seconds after, and it did so after some other tweaks, but same story.
It feels like a software issue and i have no idea on what it could be

Comment: Have you tried transferring files in a local network? What speed can be achieved locally?

Comment: No i haven't, but other computers can connect to the internet via LAN with nominal speeds and ping. Should i run a test anyway?

Comment: Which hadrware (network card)? Which OS? Did you try to disable some hardware offload features?